# How to decrypt Laravel cookies with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel, cookies, npm

I'm currently developing a video chatting project with `reactjs`. I need to pass various user info (e.g. user name, avatar url, user id) to `reactjs`. And the website is based on `Laravel` v 5.8. So I used `Laravel` cookie to pass user info to `javascript`. But `Laravel` encrypt cookies and I don't know how to decrypt it in my `reactjs`. I think encryption is a must because they're very sensitive data. My question is:

- Is there any other better way to let `reactjs` know user information?
- Otherwise, how can I decrypt `laravel` cookie with `javascript`?

I've searched stackoverflow but I couldn't find a right answer. A well-explained answer is welcome. (like `Laravel`'s cookie encrypt algorithm, where they store public/private key and `nodejs` package recommendation, a working code snippet is best)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decrypting cookies in Laravel is done using the [EncryptCookies middleware](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.html). The cookies can also be manually decrypted using the [Crypt facade](https://laravel.io/forum/09-07-2015-cookies-encrypted) like so:

```
Crypt::decrypt(Cookie::get('locale'));
```

To me it seems like you're trying to transfer data between the front-end (react) and your back-end (laravel). A good practice for doing so is by creating an API in the back-end and consuming it in the front-end. That way you can leave the cookie encryption to laravel, while you can still access the data using react.